Convert date_part function SQL in pyspark
I copy data from SQL Server to parquet file now I'm query the parquet file using pyspark
Entry:
enter image description here
Result should be
POS_TRANSACTION_HOUR:
record1 => 0000
record2 => 2300

SELECT
    RIGHT(CONCAT('0', DATEPART(HOUR, END_DATETIME)), 2) + '00' AS POS_TRANSACTION_HOUR
FROM
    TRANS_Table

I don't know why the function DATEPART doesn't work in SQL.
I appreciate your help
Thanks!
Javier

You stated that you are querying a parquet file, but it looks like you are querying a table, which I assume you created after importing the parquet file? At any rate, have you confirmed the proper syntax for that function? Is it datepart or date_part?

I'm querying a parquet file use pyspark like this:
%%sql
SELECT
RIGHT(CONCAT('0', DATEPART(HOUR, END_DATETIME)), 2) + '00' AS POS_TRANSACTION_HOUR
FROM
TRANS_Table

DATEPART is an SQLServer extension.  It's not supported by Pyspark.  https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-sql-functions/#date-time

Also, if you have converted your parquet file to a table, then have you tried something like this... select rpad(extract(hour from date_col), 4, 0) as my_col....

just add quotes to HOUR, for example DATEPART("HOUR", END_DATETIME). if your Spark version is before 3.4, use DATE_PART(). date_part function is supported since Spark 3.0. also why not just using date_format(END_DATETIME, "HH00") to fetch this info?

Spark does not support DATE_PART function, which is available in some DBMs like Postgre.
To achieve the same result with Spark SQL you can use the function HOUR, which is used to get the hour from a timestamp column.
Your code would be:
SELECT
POS_TRANSACTION_START_TIME,
RIGHT(CONCAT('0', HOUR(POS_TRANSACTION_START_TIME)), 2) || '00' AS POS_TRANSACTION_HOUR
FROM
    TRANS_Table

Try this and tell me if it works. If it does not work properly, give me more details about the context etc (eg. parquet or a table?, why this zero at the beginning if it is not appearing in the example results?)
